# is there is a way to redirect users to another application with extra data

Tags: android, flutter, redirect, deep-linking, url-launcher

so i have a flutter application , and i have a button to redirect users to another application which is a game that have coins in it , and i have a link that gives them amount of coins , when i use the url luncher it redirect first to the web then it goes to the application  , i can make them go to the app using the AppLauncher package , but i want it with the reward , is there is  a way that i can make them go directly into the game with the amount of coins , and thanks you ,

i tried app launcher and url launcher but not the output i wanted

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow .  I have some idea to implement this . Open the App using App Luncher . and Maintain your coin in another API ?

Comment: @Rahul Kushwaha  , i dont really undetstand what you trying to say, so there is links for coins for this game , and im not the owner of it , im just getting this links and  putting it in firebase  , in my application im getting this links and put it in url launcher , and it goes first to web and then application with the reward , so how exactly i can acheive going directly to it ,

Comment: I mean ,you are owner of that game application so that you can implement this coin in that application using API. If not then you can only launch that application .Hope you understand this issues .

Comment: @Rahul Kushwaha , yeah bro i understand , so basically  you dont need to be the owner of the app since there is links for free coins daily posted , and i saw other apps working for them , in my case i can lunch the app using the url_launcher as below , but coins arent guaranted , but when i press the link on my phone it redirect me to the app with the coins , any tought ? ,
 
`launchUrl(Uri(scheme: "coinmaster", path: "coinmaster://promotions",query: encodeQueryParameters({
      "af_deeplink":"true" ,
      "campaign":'my_Coins_Secret'
    })));`